# Update Column in Another Table Based off INT value Change using MySQL AFTER UPDATE Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

Getting error after error. Basically I am trying to set a columns value to `1` in my `products` table automatically if upon update of the `product_stock` table the column `available` is greater than 0 (meaning, at least one in stock).

MPN is both a unique and foreign key in my `products` table, so as long a positive value in the column `available` in the table `product_stock` the `in_stock` value for the `mpn` in the `products` table should be set to `1`.

Two tables I'm working with:

> ## 1

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `mpn` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `in_stock` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `mpn` (`mpn`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

> ## 2

```
CREATE TABLE `product_stock` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `mpn` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `size` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `available` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `product_stock_ibfk_1` (`mpn`),
 CONSTRAINT `product_stock_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`mpn`) REFERENCES `products` (`mpn`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

And one variation of my trigger

```
DELIMITER $$

    CREATE TRIGGER ps_update AFTER UPDATE ON `product_stock`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      IF NEW.available > 0 THEN
            SET products.in_stock = 1;
      ELSE
            SET products.in_stock = 0;
      END IF;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

> Error code
>
> ## 1193 - Unknown system variable 'in_stock'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update value in another table using `SET` alone. You need to use proper `UPDATE` statement to do so.

I have also added more conditions, so that it does not fire `UPDATE` query every time. It will fire `UPDATE` only when there is a change in the `in_stock` value required.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER ps_update AFTER UPDATE ON `product_stock`

    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

      -- update only when there is a change in the available
      IF NEW.available <> OLD.available THEN 

        -- update only when item becomes in_stock
        IF NEW.available > 0 AND OLD.available <= 0 THEN 
            UPDATE products 
            SET products.in_stock = 1 
            WHERE products.mpn = NEW.mpn;

        -- update only when item becomes out_stock
        ELSEIF NEW.available <= 0 AND OLD.available > 0 THEN 
            UPDATE products 
            SET products.in_stock = 0 
            WHERE products.mpn = NEW.mpn;
        END IF;
      END IF;
   END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Didn't even mean to include that word :) Thanks for pointing that out.  Updated my question with the new error message..

Comment: @BrianBruman check the updated answer . You need to use update query

Comment: Awesome! It works.  Only thing missing is `DELIMITER $$` in the beginning for the query to process it and get the trigger enabled.  But yes, just tested it and it works. Thanks much.

Comment: @BrianBruman check the further updated answer. I have optimized it.

Comment: Perfect man, love it!  Now I'm wondering if this trigger will malfunction if the *last* size `available` row is `0` even if the mpn has stock (`> 0`) for previous rows.. Got me thinking. I'm quite new at triggers, going to look into if its possible to break out of one if a condition is met or if there's some other logic I can implement :)

Comment: And of course it does. Even if one size/row has 0 available it will revert back to out of stock (even if other sizes/rows have stock).  You got me well on track though thanks again.