# Declaring a Variable in MySQL Trigger; Referencing Same Row Type

Tags: mysql, triggers, declare

Table Data and More Info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53238816/update-column-in-another-table-based-off-int-value-change-using-mysql-after-upda)

`products_stock` has a foreign key relationship to `products` via the `mpn` column.

Basic Rundown: If an `mpn` has at least one row greater than `0` in the `available` column on my `products_stock` table, the column `in_stock` should be triggered to 1 in the `products` table to indicate stock.

If all of the `mpn`'s row(/`size` variant) are set to `0` in the `available` column, the trigger should set `in_stock` on the `products` table to 0 to indicate no stock.

The former is working great to indicate there is stock, the latter is not working at all when available is at `0`. I've deduced it down to it not being able to pass the `IF rowCount < 1 THEN` declaration.  Here's the trigger as it is now:

```
BEGIN 

    DECLARE rowCount INTEGER;

    IF NEW.available <> OLD.available THEN 
    IF NEW.available > 0 AND OLD.available <= 0 THEN 
    UPDATE 
      products 
    SET 
      products.in_stock = 1 
    WHERE 
      products.mpn = NEW.mpn;
    ELSEIF NEW.available <= 0 AND OLD.available > 0 THEN 
    SET 
      @rowCount := (
        SELECT 
          COUNT(NEW.mpn) 
        FROM 
          product_stock 
        WHERE 
          product_stock.available > 0
      );
    IF rowCount < 1 THEN 
    UPDATE 
      products 
    SET 
      products.in_stock = 0 
    WHERE 
      products.mpn = NEW.mpn;
    END IF;
    END IF;
    END IF;
    END
```

I've tried many different variants for setting `@rowCount` -- directly underneath `DECLARE rowCount INTEGER;`, embedded in the `IF` condition (as seen above), adding another AND condition in the declaration (`product_stock.available > 0 AND product_stock.mpn = NEW.mpn);`) and so forth.

The issue is `rowCount` is not putting into consideration the row's MPN when doing it's count -- and is instead counting all the rows, regardless of MPN, with `product_stock.available > 0`.

If I take out `@rowCount`, it acts as it should to trigger a 0 in `products.in_stock`, but does not put into consideration any other variants the mpn has.

Is it possible to modify the trigger/declared variable to only count the `mpn` that the `available` column is being `UPDATED` on?

Comment: Isn't `mpn` unique in your `products` table ? How come you have more than one row for an `mpn` value ?

Comment: Also, remove `@` in front of `rowCount`. You have not declared it with `@`, so you should not use `@` anywhere else either. It makes MySQL think it as a different variable.

Comment: Yes, `products` table only has a single row with one MPN.  `Product_stock` has a row for each `size` variant along with it's mpn.

Comment: Wow, that's literally all it was.  I just took off the `@` and it is working properly now :).. spent so much time trying to figure out the logic I didn't look at the obvious apparently.  Thanks again.